# Where did the modifiers tab go when you click n in graph editor?

Tags: modifiers, graph-editor

At first, there was the modifiers, but after I did some more stuff (I duplicated the object a couple of times), all it shows are view properties. Help!
[image: No modifier tab in sight]

Comment: on the left panel, you need to select the Y Euler Rotation track

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must select the actual channel name in the Graph Editor before the tabs inside the Properties Shelf will be revealed. Same goes for the Driver Editor. This threw me off for some time as well.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I didn't notice that I had the lock symbol so I couldn't actually select it.